# Polymer 2.0 + firebase can't update properly

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-2.x, polymerfire

I've got a problem using Polymer 2.0 and Firebase.
I want to update data to Firebase with `firebase-document` but when I want to update only the title, it destroy all the previous data and save only the title.

Example of the strucute before update :

```
myapp:
    categories:
        1:
            logoName: test.png
            title: test
```

And after :

```
myapp:
    categories:
        1:
            title: test bis
```

Do I have to give always the entire record and update only the field I want or can I only give the field I want to update to `saveValue`.
I try to only give the field but it doesn't seem to work

Here is a part of my code :

```
<dom-module id="categorie-form">
    <template>
        <firebase-document
            id="document"
            app-name="myapp"
            data="{{categorieData}}">
        </firebase-document>

        <iron-form id="categorieIronForm">
            <form id="categorieForm">
                <label for="title">Nom de la catégorie</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="[[name]]">
                <paper-button id="validButton" on-click="_submitCategorie" raised>valider</paper-button>
            </form>
        </iron-form>
    </template>
    <script>
        class CategorieForm extends Polymer.Element {

            static get is () { return "categorie-form" }

            static get properties () {
                return {
                    categorieData: {
                        type: Object
                    }
                }
            }

            _submitCategorie () {
                this.categorieData = {
                    title: form.title.value
                };
                this.$.document.saveValue('/categories', key)
            }
        }
        customElements.define(CategorieForm.is, CategorieForm);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
this.$.document.saveValue('/categories/1/title', key)
```

Comment: It create a new row in Firebase with the id `title` in `categories` with the new value

Comment: It update the title but instead of setting the value, it create a new object with an id and inside there is the title with the value

Comment: well i'm not a good polymer developer, i don't know but try this `/categories/1.title`

Comment: Non, error : `Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "/categories/1.title". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`. Thanks trying to help